# How to find a sibling cell using class names?

Tags: jquery, html

I have table that's generated by looping through data, like this:

```
$.each(array_rule_segments, function (key, listofwidgets) {
    //console.log('in outer loop');
    var widget_details = listofwidgets.split(',');
    var counter = key + 1
    htmlstring += '<tr id="listofwidgets_' + key + '">';
    htmlstring += '<td><input type="button" value="Remove" class="remove"/></td>';
    htmlstring += '<td name="widget_type" class="widget_type" id="widget_type' + counter + '">' + widget_details[0] + '</td>';
    htmlstring += '<td name="widget_details" class="widget_details"  id="widget_details' + counter + '">' + widget_details[1] + '</td>';
    htmlstring += '<td name="widget_order" class="widget_order" id="widget_order' + counter + '">' + widget_details[2] + '</td>';
    htmlstring += '<td name="messages" id="messages' + counter + '">' + widget_details[3] + '</td>';
    htmlstring += '</tr>';

});
```

Then later on, I have logic that checks to see if the new widget the user is trying to add to the table already exists.  For example, let's say I have a widget already in the table with a value of "1234" in the widget_details field.

I check for that like so:

```
$("#add_to_table").live("click", function () {
    var cell;
    var result = $('#summary_table tr').find('td:contains(' + $('#input_widget_details').val() + ')'); //find cell in table with same widget dteails information...     

    if (result.length > 0) {
        //check for duplicates using class names.     
        console.log(result.siblings(".widget_order").html());
        if (result.siblings(".widget_order").html() == $('#widget_order').val() && result.siblings(".widget_type").html() == $('#widget_types').val()) {
            alert("Duplicate rule segment!");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The first if statement works, it finds the row that has the matching widget details value
but, I'm not able to check the sibling cells based on their class names.
The debug statement I have where I'm trying to check the html() on the sibling yields a value of null.

I've also tried `.val()` instead of `.html()`.

Comment: `.widget_order` would not have a sibling, the sibling would be the parent of that element (`tr`) containing a like element.

Comment: Mark, thanks for editing and for the response.  Sorry for being thick but I don't understand your comment.  I'm looking for the siblings of widget_details... which widget_order would be one of, since they're both <TD>... is that not correct?

Comment: So, you want to find if any other rows have that value (`.widget_order`) text in the (`.widget_details`) text being added? Or has/is it already added?

Comment: I posted an answer so you can see how to check both the html before and after it gets added - your choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some similar code mock up, one function shows how to check the html before it is added, the other checks to see if duplicates exist in the table (what you seem to be doing)

```
var array_rule_segments = ["widget1type,widgetdetails1,widgetorder1,widget1message", "widget1type,widgetdetails1,widgetorder1,widget1message"];

function rowExistsBeforeAdd(row) {
    var newRow = $(row);
    var cell;
    var foundsome;
    var details = newRow.find('.widget_details').text();
    console.log(details);
    var result = $('#summary_table tr').find('td:contains(' + details + ')');

    console.log("result:" + result.length);
    // details match if true (has length) in incomming row
    if (result.length > 0) {
        // filter to see if other things match in the new row with the inputs
        foundsome = result.filter(function () {
            var mytype = $(this).find(".widget_type").text();
            var myorder = $(this).find(".widget_order").text();
            console.log("Type:" + mytype);
            console.log("order:" + myorder);
            console.log(myorder == $('#widget_order').val());
            console.log(mytype == $('#widget_types').val());
            return myorder == $('#widget_order').val() && mytype == $('#widget_types').val();
        });
        if (foundsome.length) {
            console.log('found' + foundsome.length);
        }
    }
    return foundsome.length;
}

function checkRow() {
    var cell;
    var foundsome;
    var details = $('#input_widget_details').val();
    console.log(details);
    var result = $('#summary_table tr').find('td:contains(' + details + ')');
    console.log("result:" + result.length);
    if (result.length > 0) {
        foundsome = result.parent().siblings().filter(function () {
            var mytype = $(this).find(".widget_type").text();
            var myorder = $(this).find(".widget_order").text();
            console.log("Type:" + mytype);
            console.log("order:" + myorder);
            console.log(myorder == $('#widget_order').val());
            console.log(mytype == $('#widget_types').val());

            return myorder == $('#widget_order').val() && mytype == $('#widget_types').val();
        });
        if (foundsome.length) {
            console.log('found' + foundsome.length);
        }
    }
    return foundsome.length;
}

function addrow() {
    $.each(array_rule_segments, function (key, listofwidgets) {
        //console.log('in outer loop');
        alert(listofwidgets.length);
        var widget_details = listofwidgets.split(',');
        var counter = key + 1;
        var htmlstring = '';
        htmlstring += '<tr id="listofwidgets_' + key + '">';
        htmlstring += '<td><input type="button" value="Remove" class="remove"/></td>';
        htmlstring += '<td name="widget_type" class="widget_type" id="widget_type' + counter + '">' + widget_details[0] + '</td>';
        htmlstring += '<td name="widget_details" class="widget_details"  id="widget_details' + counter + '">' + widget_details[1] + '</td>';
        htmlstring += '<td name="widget_order" class="widget_order" id="widget_order' + counter + '">' + widget_details[2] + '</td>';
        htmlstring += '<td name="messages" id="messages' + counter + '">' + widget_details[3] + '</td>';
        htmlstring += '</tr>';
        if (!rowExistsBeforeAdd(htmlstring)) {
            $(htmlstring).appendTo('#summary_table');
        }
        /* too late, already added!
        if (checkRow()) {
            alert('duplicates');
        }
        */
    });
}

$("#add_to_table").on("click", function () {
    addrow();
});
```

Fake markup:

```
<table id="summary_table"></table>
<button id="add_to_table">add</button>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="widget_types" value="widget1type" />
<input type="text" id="widget_order" value="widgetorder1" />
<input type="text" id="input_widget_details" value="widgetdetails1" />
```

Fiddle so you can see the console logs etc as it works: http://jsfiddle.net/QTkpw/

Comment: Mark, I'm trying to use your rowExistsBeforeAdd method.  But it's failing for me.  It's not grabbing the sibling values correctly.  Can you tell me what lines 14 and 15 is supposed to do?  I'm assuming $this refers to the result we just found?  I want to better understand your code so i can google and read up on it instead of just blindly copying! =)

Comment: `$(this).find(".widget_type")` is the `.widget_type` inside the "result" element reference - `$(this)` is the element set (singular) of the "result" currently being evaluated (result is just shortcut for `$('#summary_table tr').find('td:contains(' + details + ')')`

Comment: SO, what `result.filter` does, is take the "result" set (contains) and then filters out only those with the last row in the function returning true.  If you return "true" in a filter, that element being evaluated is returned within the returned set of element (subset of "result") that has those conditions.

Comment: the `class="widget_type"` is on a td, not a row, true so perhaps you need a filter not a find on `$('#summary_table tr').find('td:contains(' + details + ')');` change to `$('#summary_table tr').filter('td:contains(' + details + ')');` perhaps?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37132/discussion-between-dot-and-mark-schultheiss)

Answer (score 0):

you can check the class names in jQuery with

```
$("selector").attr("class")
```

that should return the class name of the element